# Как в QT вывести текст из QList в поле textEdit?

Tags: c++, qt

У меня имеется заполненный список QList. Как его можно полностью вывести в поле textEdit? Или можно как то по другому сделать?

Comment: Прям все содержимое массива? 1) создай QString tmp; 2) В Цикле QList сделай tmp=tmp+"\n"+i->name; 3) (QLineEdit*)item->setText(tmp)

Answer (score 0):

Так как QT сейчас не под рукой, напишу на псевдокоде, приближенном к QT, опираясь на доки:

```cpp
QString result; // textEdit содержит строку, значит делаем строковую переменную, пока пустую
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) // Проходим по номерам всех элементов списка
{
    result += list.at(i) + QString("\n"); // Добавляем в результирующую строку очередной элемент списка и перевод строки (чтобы каждый элемент с новой строки был)
}
textEdit.plainText = result; // Присваиваем тексту эдита полученную строку и вуаля
```

Код не самый эффективный, но работать, вроде, должен. Если есть какие-то ошибки в плане синтаксиса, кто заметит, напишите в комменты, я не проверял.

P.S. Даже не знаю, с чем тут могли возникнуть проблемы, алгоритм вроде типовой.

Comment: `textEdit.setPlainText(result);`